# Join two IO actions using the same input in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have two functions:

```
emptyDirectory, copyStubFileTo :: FilePath -> IO ()
```

I want to combine them the way as below:

```
forM_ ["1", "2"] $\n -> do
  emptyDirectory n
  copyStubFileTo n
```

Is there any other standard way built into Haskell to simplify this combination?
I mean joining two IO actions and giving them the same input.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
liftA2 (>>) emptyDirectory copyStubFileTo
```

Comment: mapM_ (liftA2 (>>) emptyDirectory copyStubFileTo) ["1", "2"]

Comment: It's hard to understand how to match '(Monad m, Applicative f) => f (m a)' with 'FilePath -> IO ()'.

Comment: @aXqd, this uses the Applicative instance for functions, which you can think of as the Reader monad.  Both functions need an environment (the FilePath parameter), so `f (m a)` is instantiated at `(FilePath ->) (IO ())` for both functions.  Then the two `IO ()` actions are combined within the `(FilePath ->)` environment using `(>>)`, resulting in the final type of `(FilePath ->) (IO ())`, more conventionally written as `FilePath -> IO ()`.  This is the same technique as Pelotom's answer.

Comment: @John I didn't know we can split type signature like that. However I don't think 'odd :: (Int ->) Bool' is valid in haskell, neither is 'odd :: Int (-> Bool)'. I've tried them in GHCi.

Comment: @aXqd: It's an abuse of notation, by analogy to operator sections such as `(+ 2)`. The real syntax would look like `((->) Int Bool)`, and the `Applicative` instance above would be `((->) FilePath)`.

Comment: @camccann Should this abuse of notation be an enhancement?

Comment: Use 'ap' to make it more flexible: return (>>) `ap` action1 `ap` action2 `ap` action3 $ "/foo/bar"

Comment: @aXqd, that idiom is obsolete.  We use applicative for that now (cf. pelotom's answer).  Also, `(>>)` takes two arguments and you have given it three.  For an arbitrary number of actions: `sequence_ . sequence [ action1, action2, action3 ] $ "/foo/bar"`

Comment: @luqui Thanks. You are right. (>>) takes only two arguments. And also, I have to import 'Control.Applicative' to use '((->) a)' instance. BTW, I think 'ap' is just monad way of saying <*> in applicative. Hence I don't know why 'ap' is obsolete.

Comment: @aXqd it's obsolete because any instance of `Monad` should also be an instance of `Applicative`, in which case `ap` is redundant. Unfortunately, for backwards compatibility reasons `Monad` is not a subclass of `Applicative` as it should be

Comment: @pelotom That makes sense. I guess it should be 'Functor=>Applicative=>Monad' :D

Comment: @aXqd or `Functor => Pointed => Applicative => Monad`, but yeah :)

Answer (score 7):

The short answer is that no, there's no standard way.  The slightly longer answer is that you can write a `>&>` combinator yourself:

```
(>&>) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> (a -> m c) -> a -> m c
(f >&> g) x = f x >> g x
```

This does exactly what you want it to do, as you can see from the types.  Using this, you have `emptyDirectory >&> copyStubFileTo :: FilePath -> IO ()`, and so

```
mapM_ (emptyDirectory >&> copyStubFileTo) ["1", "2"]
```

Hoogle doesn't turn up anything for the type signature, unfortunately, so I think it's safe to assume that it doesn't exist.

---

Now, this wasn't my original implementation of `>&>`, because I originally looked at it in terms of a similar non-monadic combinator `(&) :: (a -> b) -> (a -> c) -> a -> (b,c)`, which I find myself reimplementing with some regularity.  If you approach this non-monadically and then generalize, you end up with what I think is a collection of useful combinators (which I keep reinventing) that don't seem to exist anywhere standard (even though I feel like at least some of them should).  On the chance that you ever want some more general combinators, here they are; none of these seem to exist on Hoogle.  (Choosing appropriate precedences is left as an exercise for the interested reader.)

To start, you want `(&) :: (a -> b) -> (a -> c) -> a -> (b,c)`, which is the non-monadic version of what you want.  You can't coalesce the `b` and `c`, since they're arbitrary types, so we return a tuple.  There's only one sensible function of this type: `(f & g) x = (f x, g x)`.  If we feed this implementation through `pointfree`, we get something nicer:

```
(&) :: Monad m => m a -> m b -> m (a,b)
(&) = liftM2 (,)
```

This works for functions because `(r ->)` is a monad (the reader monad); `(&)` captures the concept of doing two things and collecting both results, and for `(r ->)`, "doing something" is evaluating a function.

With this, however, you'd have `emptyDirectory & copyStubFileTo :: FilePath -> (IO (), IO ())`.  Oog.  We thus want to lift the monad out of the tuple, so we need a function `tupleM :: Monad m => (m a, m b) -> m (a,b)`.  Writing this ourselves, it uses the `&` function from above:

```
tupleM :: Monad m => (m a, m b) -> m (a,b)
tupleM = uncurry (&)
```

If you look at the types, this actually makes sense, though it might take a few reads (it did for me).

Now, we can define a version of `(&)` for monadic functions:

```
(<&>) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> (a -> m c) -> a -> m (b, c)
f <&> g = tupleM . (f & g)
```

We now have `emptyDirectory <&> copyStubFileTo :: FilePath -> IO ((),())`, which is an improvement.  But we really don't need that tuple (although we might for more interesting operations).  Instead, we want `(>&>) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> (a -> m c) -> a -> m c` (the analog of `>>`), which is what we set out to define (and, in fact, defined above).  Since I'm defining all sorts of combinators anyway, I'm going to define this by way of `<.> :: Functor f => (b -> c) -> (a -> f b) -> a -> f c` (the functorial analogue of [`<=<`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v%3a-60--61--60-) from Control.Monad).

```
(<.>) :: Functor f => (b -> c) -> (a -> f b) -> a -> f c
(f <.> g) x = f <$> g x

(>&>) :: (Monad m, Functor m) => (a -> m b) -> (a -> m c) -> a -> m c
f >&> g = snd <.> (f <&> g)
```

(If you don't like the `Functor m` constraint, replace `<$>` with `` `liftM` ``.)  What's most interesting about this is that we've arrived at a completely different implementation of `>&>`.  The first implementation focuses on the "do two things" aspect of `>&>`; the second focus on the "evaluate two functions" aspect.  This second one is actually the first implementation I thought of; I didn't try writing the first implementation, because I *assumed* it would be ugly.  There's probably a lesson in that :-)

Comment: I like all this ASCII-art in Haskell. It makes me smile. (like a `:>` combinator`)

Comment: For future reference, you can save yourself a bit of effort next time: `(Control.Arrow.&&&) :: (Arrow ~>) => (a ~> b) -> (a ~> c) -> (a ~> (b, c))`. Your `(<&>)` is the same thing on Kleisli arrows instead of pure functions.

Comment: In fact, your "do two things" `(>&>)` is just `(>>)` after adding a `ReaderT` transformer, which makes sense; and the "evaluate two functions" `(>&>)` is `\f g -> f &&& g >>> arr snd` for the Kleisli arrow, which also makes sense.

Comment: @camccann: Thanks.  I've used arrows before, but I don't understand them yet.  And I think Hoogle won't unify function arrows with other types, so `(&&&)`, `(***)`, and friends don't turn up there.

Comment: It seems you are correct about Hoogle, which certainly explains why you wouldn't have noticed `(&&&)`. At any rate, the main thing to understand is that working with `Arrow`s is basically all about writing in an uncurried pointfree style; so the combinators in `Control.Arrow` are helpful for that even if all you use is plain old `(->)`.

Answer (score 6):

Disclaimer: I think your original code is very readable and there's nothing wrong with repeating the variable `n` twice.

That said, if you want to get fancy, `((->) a)` forms an `Applicative` instance, so you can do something like this:

```
import Control.Applicative

forM_ ["1", "2"] $ (>>) <$> emptyDirectory <*> copyStubFileTo
```

Comment: :) yes, I understand. 'mapM_ (emptyDirectory >&> copyStubFileTo) ["1", "2"]' copied from Antal's answer is what I want. I thought something like '>&>' has been built into Haskell.

Comment: @aXqd: It has, sort of--it's the same thing as `(>>)` for `ReaderT FilePath IO`. But using monad transformers is clumsy for something so simple.

Answer (score 4):

You can try something like `mapM_`:

```
mapM_ ($input) [list of functions]
```

So in your case:

```
mapM_ forM_ [emptyDirectory, copyStubFileTo] . flip ($) $ ["1", "2"]
```

Untested. But should be similar.

Comment: 'mapM_ ($ input) [list of functions]' makes sense. It can combine those lines within that 'do' block into one line => 'mapM_ ($ n) [emptyDirectory, copyStubFileTo]'. I don't know if Control.Arrow can take this further. Thanks any way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure I understand this entirely, but here it goes. (basically, I stole this idea from FUZxxl but simplified and explained it)

```
mapM_ (forM_ [list of inputs]) [list of functions]
```

For example

```
mapM_ (forM_ ["foo", "bar"]) [putStrLn, putStrLn . reverse]
```

Produces

```
foo
bar
oof
rab
```

This can be generalized

```
xs >.> fs = mapM_ (forM_ xs) fs
```

So this would produce the same output

```
main = ["foo","bar"] >.> [putStrLn, putStrLn . reverse]
```

Plus, `>.>` is a funny face.

Basically, mapM_ takes a function and a list, and applies the function to each member of the list. So we create the function `(forM_ ["foo", "bar"])` which has the type `(Monad m) => (String -> m b) -> m ()`. It expects a function to be input. Lucky for us, each member of the second list is a function! And so each function in the second list will be fed to this higher-order function, producing the desired effect.